# average on date functions

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am aware that we cannot use mathematical functions on columns with dates in a table. But I came across the following SQL statement which converts the date into number

```
SELECT avg(ORDER_DATE-SYSDATE) FROM ORDERS; 
TABLE NAME ORDERS 

COLUMNS     DATATYPE        
ORDER_DATE : SYSDATE
ORDER_AMT:   NUMBER
```

I would like to know how the above sql statement converts the date into number

Comment: Do you want to calculate standard deviation or do you want to calculate the mean date value?

Comment: @zaratustra : I would to calculate the mean date value, not the standard deviation.

Comment: see my answer below, it calculates the mean date value.

Comment: `ORDER_DATE-SYSDATE` doesn't "*convert*" a date into a number. It calculates the number of days between two dates. This is all explained in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/sql_elements001.htm#SQLRF00208

Answer (score 0):

Here is the mean date value:

```
with t(d) as (
  select sysdate from dual union all
  select sysdate + 1 from dual union all
  select ADD_MONTHS(sysdate, 1) from dual 
)
SELECT avg((d - to_date('01-01-1970', 'MM-DD-YYYY'))*24*60*60*1000)/24/60/60/1000 + to_date('01-01-1970', 'MM-DD-YYYY') difference_in_ms
  FROM t
```

1. `(d - to_date('01-01-1970', 'MM-DD-YYYY')` it gives the number of days between the `d` date value (value from your table) and `01-01-1970` it gives you the value of the difference
2. `the value of the difference*24*60*60*1000` calculates the number of milliseconds between the `d` date value (value from your table) and `01-01-1970` (since one day has 24 hours, one hour has 60 minutes, one minute has 60 seconds, one second has 1000 milliseconds)
3. then the query calculates the average number of milliseconds over your table
4. then the average number of milliseconds converts back to days using `/24/60/60/1000` you get the average number of days over your table.
5. then I add this average number of days to the `01-01-1970` date (because I subtract it earlier) and it gets you the average date (when you add number to date you add days to date)

Comment: Appreciate your solution. I do not understand the following part SELECT avg((d - to_date('01-01-1970', 'MM-DD-YYYY'))*24*60*60*1000)/24/60/60/1000 + to_date('01-01-1970', 'MM-DD-YYYY') difference_in_ms
  FROM t

how are you multiplying a date value into milliseconds?

Comment: Great! It answered my doubts.